# How can I connect the Submit button to my .py file?

Tags: python, django

The goal of my program is to place the first and last name into my database upon it being entered and `Submit` button clicked by the user so that when I manually check in `Terminal` what’s in my database, I can see what the user has entered and submitted.  I need to some how connect my `Submit` button to my `views.py` file so that it can go through , sort like an `onClick()` but this time, to go a `.py` file.  (correct me if I’m wrong with this train of thought).

How would I go about making this happen?

Here's my `views.py` file:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Person

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.POST.get('firstName')
        last_name = request.POST.get('lastName')
        if first_name and last_name:
            user = Person.objects.create(firstName=first_name, lastName=last_name)
            user.save()
    return render(request, 'music/index.html')

def detail(request, user_id): # Testing out page 2
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Page # (testing this out) " + str(user_id) + "</h2>")
```

Here's my `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>The Page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="#">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="Enter first name" name="firstName">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Enter last name" name="lastName">
            </div>
        </form>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember">Remember me</label></div></br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your form should be declared as:

```
<form method="POST">
```

and your `<button type="submit">` should be inside the `<form></form>`.

As the same view deals with the GET and POST methods, you should remove the `action="#"` attribute, that way action will point to the same view.